# Don't resize stack content when changing text font to bold in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an horizontal stack with two Text :

```
HStack {
    Text("text1")
    Text("text2")
}
```

At some point, when I change the first text font to a bold one, it obviously resizes it and pushes the second text on the right.

I would like to avoid this. The label could go on a second line for sure, the frame could resize vertically but I want to keep it static horizontally.

Not sure what is the best way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well what do you want to do with the extra space that is needed for the bold text? It has to go *somewhere*...

Comment: Can we anticipate it ? Like the text frame already has enough place for it and when it changes the frame doesnt resize ?

Comment: You can use `Spacer()`, they absorb any changes if placed evenly throughout or use `SwiftUI.Layout` to place the `Text` in specific spots like evenly spread.

Comment: @loremipsum I don't think OP wants the text to be evenly spread (?) I think they want the two `Text`s to as close together as possible, but still have enough space between them for bold text to expand.

Comment: @Sweeper a plain `HStack` (Code example) evenly spreads the `View`s within, of course with size into consideration and layout priority but overall evenly spread on X the issue is size that size changes making the second `Text` adjust. Also, I mentioned evenly spread as an example since that is what their code does but you can easily adjust with wither suggestion. At no point does the OP say or even imply "as close as possible". `fixedSixe` on the horizontal and not vertical might be a solution too, to make this as close as possible but that wasn't implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a fixed width:

```
Group {
    if bold {
        Text("text1").bold()
    } else {
        Text("text1")
    }
}.frame(width: 50)
```

If there is not enough horizontal space, the text will just wrap to the next line.

Alternatively, put the "smaller" text (the non-bold one) as an overlay of the "bigger" text. Then make the bigger text invisible.

```
if bold {
    Text("text1").bold()
} else {
    // invisible bold text...
    Text("text1").bold().opacity(0)
        .overlay {
            // ...with the non-bold text as an overlay
            Text("text1")
        }
}
```

This can be also written as:

```
Text("text1").bold().opacity(bold ? 1 : 0)
    .overlay {
        if !bold {
            Text("text1")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution without fixed width does the trick :) !